# discrete fourier transform exception

Tags: opencv, dft

My discrete fourier transform (DFT) algo somehow throws the following exception:

OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (!fixedType() || ((Mat*)obj)->type() == mtype) in create, file /Users/name_x/Desktop/working/opencv/modules/core/src/matrix.cpp, line 2087
2014-07-19 19:36:17.550 OpenCV_TemplateMatching[1051:60b] program end
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type cv::Exception: /Users/name_x/Desktop/working/opencv/modules/core/src/matrix.cpp:2087: error: (-215) !fixedType() || ((Mat*)obj)->type() == mtype in function create

What could be the reason ?

The exception seems to happen at the planes initialization:

```
cv::Mat planes[] = { cv::Mat_<float>(padded), cv::Mat::zeros(padded.size(), CV_32F) };
```

Here is the entire code:

```
cv::Mat cv_img = [in_image CVMat];
cv::Mat cv_img_gray = [in_image CVGrayscaleMat];

// Do some OpenCV stuff with the image

cv::Mat padded;                                 //expand input image to optimal size
int m = cv::getOptimalDFTSize( cv_img.rows );
int n = cv::getOptimalDFTSize( cv_img.cols );
// on the border add zero values
cv::copyMakeBorder(cv_img, padded, 0, m - cv_img.rows, 0, n - cv_img.cols, cv::BORDER_CONSTANT, cv::Scalar::all(0));

// !!!! Here the exception occurs - Why ?????
cv::Mat planes[] = { cv::Mat_<float>(padded), cv::Mat::zeros(padded.size(), CV_32F) };

cv::Mat complexI;
cv::merge(planes, 2, complexI);         // Add to the expanded another plane with zeros

cv::dft(complexI, complexI);            // this way the result may fit in the source matrix

// compute the magnitude and switch to logarithmic scale
// => log(1 + sqrt(Re(DFT(I))^2 + Im(DFT(I))^2))
cv::split(complexI, planes);                   // planes[0] = Re(DFT(I), planes[1] = Im(DFT(I))
cv::magnitude(planes[0], planes[1], planes[0]);// planes[0] = magnitude
cv::Mat magI = planes[0];

magI += cv::Scalar::all(1);                    // switch to logarithmic scale
cv::log(magI, magI);

// crop the spectrum, if it has an odd number of rows or columns
magI = magI(cv::Rect(0, 0, magI.cols & -2, magI.rows & -2));

// rearrange the quadrants of Fourier image  so that the origin is at the image center
int cx = magI.cols/2;
int cy = magI.rows/2;

cv::Mat q0(magI, cv::Rect(0, 0, cx, cy));   // Top-Left - Create a ROI per quadrant
cv::Mat q1(magI, cv::Rect(cx, 0, cx, cy));  // Top-Right
cv::Mat q2(magI, cv::Rect(0, cy, cx, cy));  // Bottom-Left
cv::Mat q3(magI, cv::Rect(cx, cy, cx, cy)); // Bottom-Right

cv::Mat tmp;                           // swap quadrants (Top-Left with Bottom-Right)
q0.copyTo(tmp);
q3.copyTo(q0);
tmp.copyTo(q3);

q1.copyTo(tmp);                    // swap quadrant (Top-Right with Bottom-Left)
q2.copyTo(q1);
tmp.copyTo(q2);

normalize(magI, magI, 0, 1, CV_MINMAX); // Transform the matrix with float values into a
// viewable image form (float between values 0 and 1).
```

Comment: Could it be that dft needs a gray-image (instead of RGB) ??

Comment: Well it's not normal to do a fourier transform on a colour image, what is it you're trying to achieve?

Comment: @Roger: I am trying to find criteria for an image recognition job and I am currently looking at some sort of patterns within the DFT-converted images. It does not necessarily need to be dft with colored images. For now, I stick with the grey that actually works fine. The color information I can achieve with a split (into hsv images) for example...

Comment: Ok then stick with grey for the dft - maybe if you posted some example images, we might come up with ideas for features. Did you already try SIFT/SURF or does that not apply to your recognition task?

Comment: @Roger: The images I deal with are only about 100x100 pixels (maybe 150x150 pixels). The images show stone-morphologies. What I am trying to do is to distinguish the morphologies. At least, the algorithm should tell me whether two images originate from the same geographical location. Here you can find two or three example-images: [link](https://www.wuala.com/skuenstler/Photos/opencv/?key=wSksBqIhMIw2).

Comment: So this is texture classification? If so, take a look at [this paper from MS](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/manik/pubs%5Cvarma05.pdf) and the older, but still excellent [book by Maria Petrou](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/book/10.1002/047003534X) (now sadly passed away).

Comment: @Roger: Thank you for the links ! This is very interesting. I guess, the algorithms in the paper do take some time to implement in opencv. In terms of short amout of time, I was thinking of using "GLCM" (grey-level-cooccurrence matrix) to narrow down the texture classification. But it seems that GLCM was taken out of opencv. Any clue on how to still do so ? Do I have to implement GLCM from scratch or is there a newer (or similar) function to GLCM that is already built in opencv ?

Comment: GLCM *is* still there in Opencv (at the moment anyway), it's in the `legacy` module, so maybe that's a way forward?

Comment: Thank you so much, Roger! I give it a try...